# What locations in the USA have FIDE approved tournaments frequently?

Tags: tournament, fide

USA does not have a lot of FIDE tournaments.

Are there any locations that have them more often than some small areas that may only hold one and never do another one?

Answer (score 2):

All FIDE rated tournaments have to be registered in advance with FIDE. Once registered with FIDE they appear on the FIDE website. The page for the USA is [here](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=USA).

As you can see the US is very poorly served for FIDE rated tournaments. The main centers are New York, San Francisco, LA and St Louis.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I figured.  Too much travel and expense to play in them unless you live in those locations.

Comment: There's a bit of a bootstrapping problem as well.  If I understand the FIDE rating regulations correctly, a game played by an unrated (by FIDE) player isn't rateable unless it's played against an opponent who already has a FIDE rating.  Plus, FIDE rated tournaments have to be run by FIDE licensed arbiters, of which there are comparatively few in the US.